# Do Genesis 20 and 26 refer to the same Abimelech?

Tags: genesis

In Genesis 26:1

> Now there was a famine in the land, besides the previous famine that
> had occurred in the days of Abraham. So Isaac went to Gerar, to
> **Abimelech** king of the Philistines.

Is this the same Abimelech from Genesis 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that it's the same person, 75 years later. According to the JPS commentary on the Tanakh:

> This is a fairly common ancient West Semitic personal name. It appears
> as ʾabmlk in the Ugaritic texts and as abimilki, king of Tyre, in the
> El-Amarna correspondence (second half 14th cent. B.C.E.). It also
> appears as an Israelite name that means “my father is king.”

Sarna, N. M. (1989). Genesis (p. 141). Philadelphia: Jewish Publication Society.

There are 67 encounters with an Abimelech from Genesis to 1 Chronicles. I think of it like Pompey, ruler of Egypt who always has a sister/wife named Cleopatra.

Answer (score 0):

Both encounters with Abimelech via Abraham and Isaac, he had the same commander of his army, Phichol. So unless both names/titles are that common, what are the chances a different Abimelech had a commander names Phichol? Likely these two particular encounters are with the same Abimelech.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hamilton, in the NICOT commentary, writes:

> The Abimelech of ch. 20 cannot be the same Abimelech of ch. 26, if one
> takes the years and figures of Genesis seriously. The adult and
> married Abimelech of ch. 20 enters the Abraham story before Abraham
> reaches the age of 100. The Abimelech of ch. 26 comes much later,
> after Abraham’s death at the age of 175. Isaac is now 60 (25:26) and
> his two boys have grown up. Hence the Abimelech of ch. 20 and the
> Abimelech of ch. 26 are separated by at least seventy-five years, and
> we must be dealing with two individuals with the same name. The same
> must be the case with Phicol (21:22; 26:26). This is probably an
> instance of dynastic or royal names borne by a number of individuals
> such as one finds in the English monarchy with Henry, George, or
> Edward. Note that the title of Ps. 34 is “A Psalm of David, when he
> feigned madness before Abimelech”; yet 1 Sam. 21:10–15 identifies the
> king as Achish. These texts are not necessarily contradictory; they
> may show that among earlier and later Philistine kings Abimelech was a
> favorite throne name to assume alongside one’s own name.
>
> (Victor P. Hamilton, The Book of Genesis, Chapters 18–50, New
> International Commentary on the Old Testament. Accordance electronic
> ed. (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1995), 192.)

Hamilton's conclusion is that it is a *family name* that is handed down.  A slightly different conclusion (that I prefer) is that אֲבִימֶּ֥לֶךְ, Abimelek is a *title*, like Pharaoh. That would explain its repeated use.